# Is there a paste-replace shortcut?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, shortcuts, copy-paste, clipboard, text-editing

Hello all :) This *is* be a petty request, but it is like an itch to me right now for a specific project:

There are shorcuts for copy and paste, but I often find myself moving bits of text between each other in circles. What I do is paste next to what I want to replace (buffer step), and then copy it.

I'm wondering if I can avoid the buffer step make this a one shot operation. Is there a shortcut somewhere that enables me to select text and have it go in the clipboard when I paste over it?

My OS windows, but the question is valid or all OSes, all plugins that could provide this.

Best regards

Comment: Someone asked a similar question about doing this in [Visual Studio](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8250513/how-to-swap-clipboard-contents-for-current-selection-in-visual-studio). There's no native support but someone linked to an AutoHotkey script to do the swap.

Answer (score 0):

Here you have [AutoHotKey](http://autohotkey.com) script for that:

```
^CapsLock:: ;work with clipboard: swap clipboard and selection
    ClipboardOld := ClipboardAll
    Clipboard =     ;empty the clipboard so ClipWait statement can wait until it is filled
    Send ^c
    ClipWait, , 1
    ClipboardNew := ClipboardAll
    Clipboard := ClipboardOld
    ClipboardOld =  ;free the memory in case the clipboard was very large
    Sleep 250   ;wait until Clipboard is updated
    Send ^v
    Sleep 250   ;wait until Paste operation is completed
    Clipboard := ClipboardNew
    ClipboardNew =  ;free the memory in case the clipboard was very large
    Return
```

- The hotkey is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>CapsLock</kbd> but you can change it to anything else.
  I am using <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> (dentoed as `^#x` which is `Ctrl`+`Win`+`x`)